# Access webserver without a router

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, webserver

I have a local webserver (nginx on a Raspberry Pi) with a static IP (10.120.11.31).  Plugging it into my router, I can access it by my laptop which has a dynamic ip (ipconfig shows it as 10.120.11.186 with mask 255.255.255.0 and 10.120.11.1 which all looks good).

I then disconnect both machines from the network, and put a standard CAT-5 Ethernet cable between the two machine's Ethernet jacks, but can no longer access the webserver by putting the webserver's IP in the laptop's browser.

Do I just need a crossover cable, or is there more?

Thanks

Comment: You need to configure the network interfaces of both devices. Even the Pi probably has a gateway set.

Comment: @Seth  Yes it does have a gateway set.  I guess that wouldn't exist anymore if I remove the router.  Do I want to configure both to point at each other?   `michael@greenbean2:~ $ ip route | grep default
default via 10.120.11.1 dev eth0  metric 202`

Comment: No. You'd just need to give them an IP within the same subnet. That should be sufficient. Verify whenever the dynamic client still has its assignment.

Comment: @Seth  Ah, no, it has a 169.154 assignment.  The purpose of the Rasp Pi is not a webserver, and the only purpose of the webserver is to allow a non-techy to change some settings such as the ip, gateway, and mask as well as others.  Having the user reconfigure the gateway of both the Pi as well as their machine kind of defeats the purpose.  Is there anything I could do so they just get shipped a Pi (and maybe a special cable), plug it into their router or pc, and can access it via a browser so they can change its ip and mask to something on their network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is what the IETF (the IP standards body) calls "Zero Configuration Networking" or "ZeroConf".

It was developed specifically for the kind of case you're talking about. If I hook two or more machines together via Ethernet, they should be able to get addresses and talk to each other and discover each others services even without some sysadmin setting up a router or DHCP server or manual IP configurations or whatnot.

Here's a [Raspberry Pi ZeroConf HOWTO from Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/bonjour-zeroconf-networking-for-windows-and-linux/overview). That may be all you need. Read on below for background details.

ZeroConf, as a technology, has three parts:

1. Self-assigned link-local IP addressing so machines can get IP addresses without a DHCP server, and without being manually configured. Those are the `169.254.0.0/16` IPv4 addresses everyone's seen, along with `fe80::` IPv6 addresses.
2. Multicast DNS (mDNS) name resolution. This allows systems to advertise their names like "Raspberry-Pi.local" or "Spiffs-Mac.local", via multicasts on the local LAN, without the need for a unicast DNS server. So you could type something like "http://rpi.local/" to get to the web server on your RPi.
3. [m]DNS Service Discovery (DNS-SD). This allows devices to advertise what services they provide (and the names of those services), not just their hostname. So they could advertise that they're a printer, or a web server, or have an sshd listener, or all of the above, etc.

Apple's implementation of ZeroConf is known as "Bonjour" (provided by the "mDNSResponder" daemon, which is open source). Besides mDNSResponder which is common on Apple products, Android devices, and many embedded devices, there's also the open source "Avahi" package that's a part of many desktop/laptop, router, and other embedded Linux distros. I believe OpenWrt even created its own implementation called simply "mDNS", so that's a third open source implementation.

UNFORTUNATELY, Microsoft has never natively supported true IETF ZeroConf, and instead polluted the space with a knockoff they call LLMNR, which also uses the ".local" namespace, causing conflicts. BUT, Apple provides an mDNSResponder-based ZeroConf implementation for Windows in the form of [Bonjour Print Services for Windows](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL999). (Don't let the name fool you, it's a full ZeroConf implementation, not limited to printing.)

By the way, you should *not* need a crossover cable, because Raspberry Pi's Ethernet port contains an auto-crossover (auto MDI-X) PHY.

Comment: Excellent and complete answer

Comment: Thank you Spiff!  Agree, great answer.  Haven't implemented it yet, but will give it a try.  And thank you for saving me a trip and $20 for a trip to radioshack for a crossover cable!